# How to import JSON file with different file extension in TypeScript?

Tags: json, typescript, import

I want to import a JSON file which doesn't have a `.json` file extension. For example `foo.myext`:

```json
{"something": "some data"}
```

I tried to declare the file type:

```
// declarations.d.ts
declare module "*.myext" {
  const json: {something: string};
  export default json;
}
```

In my `tsconfig.json` I have the following:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "typeRoots": ["./src/declarations.d.ts"]
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

And inside code I import it as:

```
import foo from "./foo.myext";

console.log(foo.something);
```

This works at compile time, but at runtime it turns out that the imported value (`foo`) is actually a string that just contains the filename.

If I rename the file to use `.json` extension, importing works fine. But I'd really like to keep the original file extension.

## Update

I tried overriding the WebPack config using [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired). Created the following `config-overrides.js`:

```js
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  return {
    ...config,
    module: {
      ...config.module,
      rules: [
        ...config.module.rules,
        {
          test: /\.myext$/,
          use: [{ loader: "json-loader" }],
        },
      ],
    },
  };
};
```

Also installed `json-loader` dependency.

But the problem stays the same - the file is still imported as just a filename string :(

When I run `yarn build` I see the JSON file being converted to JavaScript file in `/build/static/media/foo.81ac3f28.myext`:

```js
module.exports = {"something": "some data"}
```

So the Webpack config sort of works... but not quite.

Comment: Might be a typo, but `declarations.d.ts` !== `declerations.d.ts`

Comment: How are you building this project? Is webpack involved?

Comment: @spender Thanks. Fixed the typo in filename. Looks like `declarations.d.ts` file was imported regardless of the typeRoots config in `tsconfig.json`. As a result nothing changed.

Comment: Yep, I am using Webpack. Completely forgot about that. Guess this is something I need to configure inside webpack config. Though I'm using it through create-react-app, so I have no webpack config around. Perhaps will need to eject the app... will have to research a bit...

Comment: OK. So CRA then, I guess. Don't eject. How about forcing the loader with some inline magic? Something like `import foo from "json-loader!./foo.myext";` See [here](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/json-loader/) and [here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline)

Comment: When using this syntax (after installing `json-loader`) I get a strange error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0". I emptied up the JSON file completely, so there clearly is no `e` inside there - but the error persists. When I delete the file, I do get "no such file or directory" as expected.

Comment: I think this `e` might be the result of trying to parse the filename `/static/media/foo.81ac3f28.myext` as JSON/JavaScript. I guess the `/static/m` can be parsed as regex literal, and `e` after that is no more valid syntax.